# What additional documents do I need to bring from Indonesia to Belgium to apply for a family reunion visa with my husband (Dutch citizen)?

Tags: netherlands, dependent-visa, belgium, eu-spouses

I am Cherry living in Indonesia I am married Netherlands since 2 years ago. And we had registered our marriage in the *gemeente* in the Netherlands. I have 4 children, the oldest 27 yo, 25 yo, 22 yo, 17 yo. I have a Schengen multi-entry visa valid until 2018 and I have visited my husband a few times. My husband has got a job as a technician near Belgium and living in Netherlands for now. But he wants to move to Belgium next month and asked me and my children to come to Netherlands and then we would be moving together in to Belgium together. What documents would be needed to prepared from Indonesia for me and my children to get a family reunion visa in Belgium?

Comment: Have you checked with the Belgian consulate?

Comment: Your children over 18 will not be eligible, if I recall correctly, unless they are still dependent.

Comment: If I understand correctly those children are yours but not your husband's? I believe this makes things even more difficult. For you (but not your children), noving/getting a residence card should actually be easier once your husband lives in Belgium. I don't see any advantage (and a lot of additional fees and paperwork) in moving to the Netherlands first. And if he is going to move next month, you simply do not have time for a family reunification procedure in the Netherlands anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to legalize your marriage and kids birth certificates in the Belgium embassy/consulate in Jakarta.  Give them a call and ask. This I think is the most important. Amro

Comment: It may be easier to do it in the Belgian municipality since the marriage was in the Netherlands.